# Odd issue with my Angular app: Object passed in from controller to service ends up as undefined in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with my angular app: the js object I pass in from the controller to the service always ends up as `undefined` when it reaches the service.

My controller (`$scope.passwordResetForm` always evaluate to a proper js object here):

```
$scope.sendPasswordResetInformation = function () {
  passwordService.sendPasswordResetInformation($scope.passwordResetForm,
  function () {},
  function (data) {});
};
```

My service (`passwordResetForm` is always `undefined` here...):

```
        sendPasswordResetInformation: function (passwordResetForm, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            return $http.post('/api/password/send-reset-information', passwordResetForm)
                .success(function () {
                    successCallback();
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    errorCallback(data);
                });
        }
```

Can anyone please help?

**edit 1**: I am confused. After adding a console log in the controller, I noticed that $scope.passwordResetForm is indeed undefined in the controller. What confused me was the debug info in the chrome console. See below:

```
this: ChildScope
$$ChildScope: null
$$childHead: null
$$childTail: null
$$listenerCount: Object
$$listeners: Object
$$nextSibling: null
$$prevSibling: null
$$watchers: Array[3]
$$watchersCount: 0
$id: 5
$parent: Object
passwordResetForm: Object
email: "me@gmail.com"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

**edit 2**:

Adding this in the controller sorted the issue:

```
$scope.passwordResetForm={};
```

Because the ng-model is an object:

```
ng-model="passwordResetForm.email"
```

Comment: Use Google chrome source to debug your controller:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: If you place a `console.log($scope.passwordResetForm)` before the service call and another `console.log` right when you enter the function you're seeing 2 different things?

Comment: Yes that's what I used to figure out the above...

Comment: Omri aharon: bear with me...

Comment: I am editing my post.

Comment: @Jbigman Yes: problem solved!